# Is there a way to check the Play Store app versionCode?

Tags: android, google-play

All is in the title :

Do you know a way (GooglePlay Services ? Free Api ?) to check to current versionCode available on the Play Store ?

I can see that some users of my app still use several old version. So I want to add a preference to check if the app is up to date.

Thanks in advance for helping !

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [android-query](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/) for that.

It will give you a result like : https://androidquery.appspot.com/api/market?app=com.google.android.youtube

Comment: Yes, it seems that this lib should do the trick. Never heard of it before, thanks a lot. Going test it and accept your answer then.

Comment: Works fine. Thanks !
Do you know if there is a way to update some strings of the library ?

Answer (score 2):

Recently introduced [Play Core library](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates#update_readiness) gives Version Code of the app.

```kotlin
// Creates instance of the manager.
val appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(context)

// Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
val appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo

// Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
    {
        appUpdateInfo.availableVersionCode()
    }
}
```

The [AppUpdateManager.AppUpdateInfo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/appupdate/AppUpdateInfo) will give the latest updatable VersionCode number from Play Store.

Note that it does not give `VersionName` string value.

Comment: I've tried to use the availableVersionCode but it seems to just give me my actual version code of the build im running rather than whats on the play store